# Unexpected strange code showing on browser when I run this example

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

So I found an web files for learning, but sadly there is no tutorial how to install them. Anyway I'm not a totally newbie but still can't understand what's wrong. I have installed xampp, put all files to htdocs, I uploaded database, changed database login,pass,name in those files but I'm getting this error while trying to access website:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhIBy.png]

This is index.php file

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vilnius');
if(substr(StrToLower($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]), 0, 4) != 'www.') {
    $rto = 'http://www.' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    header('Location: '. $rto);
}

require_once 'class/mysql.class.php';
require_once 'class/users.class.php';
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'Page.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    user()->Join($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
    header("location: /");
}

if(!empty($_GET["psl"])) {
    $id = explode('/', $_GET['psl']);
} else {
    $id = array("start");
} 
$_page = array_shift($id);
$page = new Page($_page);
echo $page->build($id);
?>
```

Comment: where/what is the error?

Comment: First thing to try, change `<?` to `<?php` does it run then

Comment: PHP 7+ does not support `<?` tag. You should try to change them into `<?php` first.

Comment: @KoalaYeung It doesn't?

Comment: @kerbholz No. It doesn't support that by default.

Comment: @KoalaYeung Maybe you are thinking of `asp_tags` which were removed in PHP7

Comment: @RiggsFolly: You're right. Unlike the removed`asp_tags`, you can still set `short_open_tag` to override the PHP7+ default.

Answer (score 0):

Change php open tag from

> < ?   to   < ?php

Or make sure the php short_open_tag is set to true in php.ini

Comment: Its in `php.ini` actually

Comment: Yea i tried to do it before, but then I got this https://i.imgur.com/rlbyF9l.png , maybe it's problem with database ? I created it and uploaded sql file, but not sure if I changed the right files for database user, pass and name. I found mysql.class.php file where I put my database login, pass and the database which I created.

Comment: @Toms make sure you  remove every occurence of it, even in the file you included via 'require_once'

Comment: @Stever Okay I got it working, but problem is if I click on any navigation it just throws me to: Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.
Not sure what does that mean, because everything is there, I mean all files in same folder.

Comment: I guess that's a different problem so you should open a new question

Comment: @Stever Okay gonna open it, just one more question, maybe it will help to solve the problem, is there a way to check if database is successfully connected ?

Comment: That is also a different problem. However, just check if your database connection variable is not equal to false